# cd ~ not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

On one of my computers cd ~ (cd tilde) has stopped working. It says the desired path can not be found.

Any idea what could cause this? I need it for git. (it does work in Git Bash though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd ~` won't work in `cmd.exe` (unless you have a directory named "`~`" - the equivalent in `cmd.exe` is just plain old `cd`.

Cygwin (and possibly other implementations of) `bash` does correctly resolve this.  Are you not running this command in `bash`?

`cd ~` may work in Powershell, though (different from `cmd.exe`)... haven't tried...

Comment: I forgot I had cygwin running on the other machine where it just worked :) Thanks

Comment: `cd ~` works in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the classic windows command prompt or windows power shell? It should work in the later but not in the former.